# Converting "[object SVGGElement]" to HTML Vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to reactively call a custom bootstrap popover component based on which svg the user is hovering over throughout the page. It is called by:

```
<template>
   <popover v-if="node != null">
      <template #content>
         Reached
      </template>
      <template #caller>
         {{node}}
      </template>
   </popover>
</template>
```

However, `{{node}}` is returning "[object SVGGElement]" rather than the expected html object.

If I use `{{node.outerHTML}}` it returns a string literal: "svg id="test"></svg"

Any suggestions to have it return as an html object? For example:

```
...
<template #caller>
   <svg id="test"></svg>
</template>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

The Svg is an SVGGElement. I suggest capturing the mouse mouseover event to set the Popover position.

Comment: Bootstrap Popover does not allow for x/y positioning. That would have to be "hacked" through styling changes which I would prefer not to do. Rather using the proper HTML elements for positioning.

Comment: If I create a Popover through JS in the Vue component using the node, it works. So why would it not be possible to deconsntruct the SVG element at the Vue template level?